hitch for trailer for ebike
I just recently bought a TerraTrike Maverick with an EBO 48v Cruiser e-bike kit. And even more recently bought a dog trailer, that I THINK came with parts standard for a non-ebike... or at least a differently speced one.
I am specifically talking about the hitch that attaches to the trike's rear hub axle.

I'm estimating that the opening is 12mm, which is a TINY bit too small to fit over my rear axle.

PS - I know the part will have to go between the nut and the frame - just didn't want to take the nut off without knowing it would fit... which it doesn't.
I've read about adapters like this one. But then I'm also seeing (for roughly the same price) hitches with a 15mm opening, like this one.
Is there any advantage to going with one over the other? Or am I WAY off in my solution to this problem?

It only needs to be marginally bigger, just drill the hole out to the correct size.

@Noise I agree - could you post that as an answer please ?

Unfortunately, that is not an option in this situation.

Drilling or filing the mount hole of your hitch to the size you need would be my preferred solution.
However, should you decide to go for another solution, the adapter you found might work well, so long as you get the proper adapter. The one you listed is m10*1. Make sure that fits. If uncertain, get a hex nut with an M10+1 - thread and see if it fits your axle.
going with a hitch with a much wider hole is not a good idea. Doing that would mean that you have a lot less material taking the force of the tightened nut. I would expect the material of the hitch to give over time, loosening the nut. While imho not overly dangerous (given that it's the rear wheel) it would still be inconvenient and might impede your rear wheel brakes, since the rim could move relative to the brake pads.
If it's really just a small amount, just get a suitable file and start by filing off the paint, then a bit more, until the hitch glides freely over the axle, without widening the hole too much.

Would you consider 15mm a "much wider hole" than 12mm?

@Daveh0 yes i would. Why: look at the contact surfaces. you'll see that the same nut on a 15 mm hole has ~1/3 - 1/2 less contact area than on a 12mm hole.

Makes sense. Thanks!
